# jquery returns undefined for data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, undefined

I tried so many things and still can't make it run

```
<span data-comment-id="123456" class="delete_co">Delete button</span>
<div class="delete_confirm" style="display: none;">
    wanna delete?
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="button" value="cancel" class="delete_cc">
        <input type="submit" name="comment_delete" value="delete">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$('.delete_co').click(function(){
    alert('' + $('.delete_co').data['comment-id']);
    $('.delete_confirm').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.delete_cc').click(function(){
    $('.delete_confirm').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urK5L/10/

Comment: Your `.data` have `[]` while it should be `()`

Comment: A good question provides some context and explains what goes wrong, eg by providing some output of eg firebug. This makes the question more useful to a larger audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `alert('' + $('.delete_co').data('comment-id'));`

not `alert('' + $('.delete_co').data['comment-id']);`

The problem is the `[]`

Comment: wow :D I tried 300 ways to fix it and I couldn't notice this tiny problem :D Thanks, I can accept your answer after 9 minutes :3

Comment: @MitkoGrjkAmaruShakur For future reference the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/ (and http://api.jquery.com/data/ for this particular method) is always useful if you aren't sure how to use a method.